# file owner and user privileges in HDFS

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs, privileges

It was my first time developing an HDFS cluster. I found that I can change file own or privilege.
What I don't understand is if I create user carl on namenode and change the owner of the /test directory in HDFS to carl. Would it work in DataNode? I have no idea, I want to know how it will work.

I am trying to search for official docs or some answers on Google. But nothing useful.

Comment: You should change HDFS file ownership by `hdfs dfs -chmod` command. It will change ownership of the file globally on HDFS level on FS level. If you then try to access given HDFS file by user from different node (no matter if it is namenode or datanode) it should work the same way as it is working for file ownership on FS level. So answer to your question would be, if you access `/test` directory as `carl` user from different node it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The blocks on the datanode should still be owned by the process running the datanode JVM..

Note: By default, Hadoop compares strings for user permissions. Adding Keberos is the only way to truly protect the access. In other words, `HADOOP_USER=carl hadoop fs -ls /test` would work. Even if I am running that command as a user named `hacker` and a user account named `carl` doesn't exist on the machine I run that command from (i.e. you should limit who can access your namenode, or protect your cluster with Kerberos, not rely on OS user accounts)